# Crackling noise on Zoom conferences

Tags: audio, virtual-machine, pulseaudio, zoom

**The setup** is the following:
Zoom running inside a Lubuntu VM. USB headset reassigned to the VM.

**The problem**: only in Zoom, the speaker of the headset does a crackling noise. (E.g. youtube music is clear. Using Skype outside of the VM works fine. Listening to Zoom on the laptop's built-in speaker works too.)

Restarting pulseaudio does not fix the problem.

**Question:** Where to start with debugging this? Is there some log that might show an error message, or some other useful information?

Comment: I actually have exactly the same issue. Did you find a way to solve it in the mean time?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I gave up on using Zoom in a VM. Since I don't want to install it on my host, I use Zoom in a web browser instead (on the host).

Comment: FWIW I seem to have succeeded on Linux with PipeWire - https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire . I need a few more tests but it seems to handle bluetooth much better than default pulseaudio